# While dentro de un do-while

Tags: c, windows, dev-c++

Mi problema es que al intentar repetir un programa con un while dentro, el programa no me mostró nada.

Este es mi código:

```
main()
{
     int i=1;

   do
   {

     printf("\nPrograma 'Serie 1-10'");

     getch();

    while(i<=10)
    {
        printf("%i, ", i);
        i++;
    }

    getch();

    printf("\nDesea repetir el programa 'Serie 1-10'? S/N ");
            scanf("%s", &continuar);
            system("cls");

  }while(continuar == 's'|| continuar =='S');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes, la funcion **getch()**; detiene el programa hasta que se presione una tecla, ademas que de que la variable continuar no se declara nunca. Otro punto es que solo imprimirá una vez la serie (1 al 10) ya que el valor de **i** en la segunda ocasión que quieras mostrar los números ya va a valer 11. Te dejo el código con la modificación.

```
    void main()
    {
       char continuar;
       do
       {
            int i=1;
            printf("\nPrograma 'Serie 1-10'");     

            while(i<=10)
            {
                printf("%i, ", i);
                i++;
            }

            printf("\nDesea repetir el programa 'Serie 1-10'? S/N ");
            scanf("%s", &continuar);
            system("cls");

      }while(continuar == 's'|| continuar =='S');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable continuar no está declarada, y cuando repite el bucle do while el i del bucle interno está en su valor máximo, es decir, 11 toca resetear en cada iteración, y para leer la variable utilice el  cin, Saludos

```
int i = 1;
char continuar;

do
{
    printf("\nPrograma 'Serie 1-10'\n");

    //getch();
    system("pause");

    while(i<=10)
    {
        printf("%i, ", i);
        i++;
    }

    i = 1;

    printf("\n\nDesea repetir el programa 'Serie 1-10'?\n S/N: ");
    cin >> continuar;
    system("cls");

}while(continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');
```